# How to assign an IP to istio-ingressgateway on localhost?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using kubespray to run a kubernetes cluster on my laptop. The cluster is running on 7 VMs and the roles of the VM's spread as follows:

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-1   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-2   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-3   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-4   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-5   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-6   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-7   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
```

I've installed https://istio.io/ to build a microservices environment.

I have 2 services running and like to access from outside:

```
k get services
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
greeter-service   ClusterIP   10.233.50.109   <none>        3000/TCP   47h
helloweb          ClusterIP   10.233.8.207    <none>        3000/TCP   47h
```

and the running pods:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-2hf4x        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.69.7    k8s-6   <none>           <none>
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-gnsvp        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.65.3    k8s-2   <none>           <none>
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-lkt6p        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.68.9    k8s-7   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-7f76v                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.64.3    k8s-1   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-pj494                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.69.8    k8s-6   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-tnqfb                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.70.7    k8s-5   <none>           <none>
```

The problem is, I can not access the services from outside, because I do not have the *EXTERNAL IP* address(remember the cluster is running on my laptop).

```
k get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system  
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.233.61.112   <pending>     15020:31311/TCP,80:30383/TCP,443:31494/TCP,15029:31383/TCP,15030:30784/TCP,15031:30322/TCP,15032:30823/TCP,15443:30401/TCP   47h
```

As you can see, the column **EXTERNAL-IP** the value is `<pending>`.

The question is, how to assign an **EXTERNAL-IP** to the `istio-ingressgateway`.

Comment: Yea, because on cloud (AWS,GCP,Azure) there is network LoadBalancer (layer 4) from where you get the external IP, on your laptop you can access it with `nodeIP:Nodeport`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, there is no way Kubernetes can assign external IP to `LoadBalancer` service.
This service type needs infrastructure support which works in cloud offerings like GKE, AKS, EKS etc.

As you are running this cluster inside your laptop, deploy [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) Load Balancer to get `EXTERNAL-IP`

Comment: @zero_coding , Yes. I've documented it in [my github](https://github.com/ansilh/kubernetes-the-hardway-virtualbox/blob/master/13.Load-Balancer.md) as well

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you can't make k8s to assign you an external IP address, as `LoadBalancer` service is Cloud Provider specific. You could push your router external IP address to be mapped to it, I guess, but it is not trivial.

To reach the service, you can do this:

1. `kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system`
2. Change the type of the service from `LoadBalancer` to `ClusterIp`. You can also do `NodePort`. Actually you can skip this step, as `LoadBalancer` service already contains `NodePort` and `ClusterIp`. It is just to get rid of that **pending** status.
3. `kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway YOUR_LAPTOP_PORT:INGRESS_CLUSTER_IP_PORT -n istio-system`

I don't know to which port you want to access from your localhost. Say 8080, you can do:

`kubectl port-forward svc/istio-ingressgateway 8080:80 -n istio-system`

Now port 8080 of your laptop (localhost:8080) will be mapped to the port 80 of `istio-ingressgateway` service.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as Suresh explained.

But if you want to access from your laptop you can use in your service type: NodePort, which gives you access from outside the cluster.

You should first obtain the IP of your cluster, then create your service with something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30000
```

After that, you can access from your laptop with: http://**cluster-ip**:30000

There is no need to create an ingress for that.

You should use a port in range (30000-32767), as stated [below](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):

> If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using minikube, just run:

```
$ minikube tunnel
```

```
$ k get svc -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.111.187.167   127.0.0.1     15021:31949/TCP,80:32215/TCP,443:30585/TCP   9m48s
```